# How to group by name and running dates only in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to make mysql query to group the data by name and consecutive dates but i am not really sure how it can be done.

```
Date                 |   Name
--------------------------------
2018-10-13 00:00:00  Charles
2018-10-14 00:00:00  Charles
2018-10-15 00:00:00  Charles
2018-10-16 00:00:00  Charles
2018-10-17 00:00:00  Charles
2018-10-18 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-19 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-20 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-21 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-22 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-23 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-24 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-25 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-26 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-27 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-28 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-29 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-30 00:00:00  Charles
2018-12-31 00:00:00  Charles
2019-01-01 00:00:00  Charles
2019-01-02 00:00:00  Charles
2019-01-03 00:00:00  Charles
```

The expect result like so

```
Name    | Date From  | Date To   |
----------------------------
Charles | 2018-10-13 | 2018-10-18|
        | 2018-12-19 | 2019-01-03|
```

Comment: You have an error in the data collected, you cannot know whether a date is a start date or an end date.

Comment: @DavidLemon Yes you can

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this process is considerably simplified by the introduction of common table expressions, but I haven't got to grips with those yet (a New Year's resolution, perhaps). In the meantime, here's one idea...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2018-10-13'),
('2018-10-14'),
('2018-10-15'),
('2018-10-16'),
('2018-10-17'),
('2018-10-18'),
('2018-12-19'),
('2018-12-20'),
('2018-12-21'),
('2018-12-22'),
('2018-12-23'),
('2018-12-24'),
('2018-12-25'),
('2018-12-26'),
('2018-12-27'),
('2018-12-28'),
('2018-12-29'),
('2018-12-30'),
('2018-12-31'),
('2019-01-01'),
('2019-01-02'),
('2019-01-03'); 

SELECT MIN(dt) range_start
     , MAX(dt) range_end 
  FROM
     (
       SELECT x.* 
            , CASE WHEN dt = @prev + INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev := dt 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev := null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY dt
     ) a
 GROUP 
    BY i;
+-------------+------------+
| range_start | range_end  |
+-------------+------------+
| 2018-10-13  | 2018-10-18 |
| 2018-12-19  | 2019-01-03 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Is there anyway this can be done without using the mysql variable @ ....because the application that i am going to use to make the report does not accept such variable

Comment: As i say, if you're using MySQL 8.0+ then look at CTE

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this Solution:

```
select a.name, adate start_date,bdate enddate from
(select min(yourdate) adate,MIN(REPLACE(yourdate,'-','')),yourdate, name from your_table  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(yourdate FROM 1 FOR 4)) a
left join
(select max(yourdate) bdate,max(REPLACE(yourdate ,'-','')),yourdate ,name from your_table GROUP BY SUBSTRING(yourdate FROM 1 FOR 4)) b
on SUBSTRING(b.yourdate FROM 1 FOR 4) = SUBSTRING(a.yourdate FROM 1 FOR 4)
```